# Bundle loses all data between two Activities

Tags: java, android

I've got two different activities Menu and Exercise.
I need to pass some data from Menu to Exercise when I start the latter activity via the click of a button.
Here is the code in Menu activity:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.temp);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(context, ExerciseActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("colors","Blue");
            b.putIntArray("workoutlist",new int[] {0,1});
            i.putExtras(b);
            //i.putExtra("workoutlist",MyApp.workoutList.get(0));
            //i.putExtra("colors","Blue");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Using debugging tools I've checked that all the data are inside the bundle of the intent properly.
And here is the code that should retrieve data from the intent in Exercise Activity:

```
    Intent in = getIntent();
    Bundle b = in.getExtras();
    String[] colorSets = (String[]) b.get("colors");
    int[] l = (int[]) b.get("workoutlist");
```

The fact is when I get the bundle it is empty, and obviously I cannot proceed.

Moreover I already used almost the same code between to other activities and everything is working fine.

Why is this happening? Is it there something I'm missing which generates this error? Maybe some incompatibility between the two activities?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are putting a single String into the bundle but trying to retrieve it and cast to an array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you add `String` using `putString()` and get it using `getString()`. the same goes for other types.

```
Intent in = getIntent();
        Bundle b = in.getExtras();
        String colorSets =  b.getString("colors");
        int[] l =  b.getIntArray("workoutlist");
```

Comment: If you are suggesting to remove the casting operator that doesn't work as it gives me an error as an object cannot be assigned to a string array

Comment: I used different methods than the ones you have used.

compare my answer with your code :D

Comment: you are using `get() ` .my answer illustrate using `getString()` and `getIntArray()`

Comment: did you get it?

Comment: Oh I beg you pardon I didn't notice that, sorry. I just tried and this really works it's amazing thank you so much!! : D Just one more thing may you be so kind to tell me why is that? What's the difference between the two approaches? And why it worked fine one time and failed this time? By the way you're great! Thank you!

Comment: `Bundle` class has many methods to put and get stored variables.
with this signature get***(), where *** is (`int`,`float` ...etc).
you should put and get the appropriate type.
read more here.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html
good luck buddy.